# Component is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have made a Vue CLI project and then started making my project.

I have made the following component named `Navigation.vue`:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav_container">
      <a href="https://www.metrici.ro/" target="_blank" class="logo"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><router-link to="/home">Home</router-link></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="touch"
            >Network Settings <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i
            ><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i
          ></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <router-link to="/dhcpIP">DHCP IP</router-link>
            <router-link to="/staticIP">Static IP</router-link>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!-- <li><router-link to="/files">Import/Export Files</router-link></li> -->
        <li><router-link to="/update">Update</router-link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Navigation',
}
</script>
<style scoped>
/* Some style  */
</style>
```

I have then imported it in `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navigation />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Navigation from "./components/Navigation.vue";
</script>

<style scoped>
  /* Some style  */
</style>
```

finally I have `main.js` which I haven't modified:

```
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and I get the following error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                    8:10:25 PM
 error  in ./src/App.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

\App.vue
  9:8  error  'Navigation' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

The component is clearly used, yet I receive that error. I don't understand why.

Comment: You are not using the `Navigation` variable you are importing. You need to use it as a component. More details here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration-in-a-Module-System

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are importing `Navigation` but never use it on your script, declare it as component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navigation />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Navigation 
  },
}
</script>
<style scoped>
/* Some style  */
</style>
```

Comment: It was right in front of me. I don't why, but it felt weird to export `App.js` without a name.

Comment: @Jorje12 Are you using  ` <Navigation />` on the same file you are importing?

Comment: I wrote `component` instead of `components`. It works just fine. Thank you.